# Invalid output return when compile this program

Tags: java

I found this example on java tutorial book.

```
public class BeerSong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int beerNum = 99;
        String word = "bottles";
        while (beerNum > 0)
        {
            if (beerNum == 1)
            {
                word = "bottle";
            }
            System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer");
            System.out.println("Take one down.");
            System.out.println("Pass it around.");
            beerNum = beerNum - 1;
            if (beerNum > 0)
            {
                System.out.println(beerNum +  " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm confused about the out put.

```
60 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
59 bottles of beer on the wall
59 bottles of beer on the wall
59 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
58 bottles of beer on the wall
58 bottles of beer on the wall
58 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
57 bottles of beer on the wall
57 bottles of beer on the wall
57 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
56 bottles of beer on the wall
56 bottles of beer on the wall
56 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
55 bottles of beer on the wall
55 bottles of beer on the wall
55 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
54 bottles of beer on the wall
54 bottles of beer on the wall
54 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
53 bottles of beer on the wall
53 bottles of beer on the wall
53 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
52 bottles of beer on the wall
52 bottles of beer on the wall
52 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
51 bottles of beer on the wall
51 bottles of beer on the wall
51 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
50 bottles of beer on the wall
50 bottles of beer on the wall
50 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
49 bottles of beer on the wall
49 bottles of beer on the wall
49 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
48 bottles of beer on the wall
48 bottles of beer on the wall
48 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
47 bottles of beer on the wall
47 bottles of beer on the wall
47 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
46 bottles of beer on the wall
46 bottles of beer on the wall
46 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
45 bottles of beer on the wall
45 bottles of beer on the wall
45 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
44 bottles of beer on the wall
44 bottles of beer on the wall
44 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
43 bottles of beer on the wall
43 bottles of beer on the wall
43 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
42 bottles of beer on the wall
42 bottles of beer on the wall
42 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
41 bottles of beer on the wall
41 bottles of beer on the wall
41 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
40 bottles of beer on the wall
40 bottles of beer on the wall
40 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
39 bottles of beer on the wall
39 bottles of beer on the wall
39 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
38 bottles of beer on the wall
38 bottles of beer on the wall
38 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
37 bottles of beer on the wall
37 bottles of beer on the wall
37 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
36 bottles of beer on the wall
36 bottles of beer on the wall
36 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
35 bottles of beer on the wall
35 bottles of beer on the wall
35 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
34 bottles of beer on the wall
34 bottles of beer on the wall
34 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
33 bottles of beer on the wall
33 bottles of beer on the wall
33 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
32 bottles of beer on the wall
32 bottles of beer on the wall
32 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
31 bottles of beer on the wall
31 bottles of beer on the wall
31 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
30 bottles of beer on the wall
30 bottles of beer on the wall
30 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
29 bottles of beer on the wall
29 bottles of beer on the wall
29 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
28 bottles of beer on the wall
28 bottles of beer on the wall
28 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
27 bottles of beer on the wall
27 bottles of beer on the wall
27 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
26 bottles of beer on the wall
26 bottles of beer on the wall
26 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
25 bottles of beer on the wall
25 bottles of beer on the wall
25 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
24 bottles of beer on the wall
24 bottles of beer on the wall
24 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
23 bottles of beer on the wall
23 bottles of beer on the wall
23 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
22 bottles of beer on the wall
22 bottles of beer on the wall
22 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
21 bottles of beer on the wall
21 bottles of beer on the wall
21 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
20 bottles of beer on the wall
20 bottles of beer on the wall
20 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
19 bottles of beer on the wall
19 bottles of beer on the wall
19 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
18 bottles of beer on the wall
18 bottles of beer on the wall
18 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
17 bottles of beer on the wall
17 bottles of beer on the wall
17 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
16 bottles of beer on the wall
16 bottles of beer on the wall
16 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
15 bottles of beer on the wall
15 bottles of beer on the wall
15 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
14 bottles of beer on the wall
14 bottles of beer on the wall
14 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
13 bottles of beer on the wall
13 bottles of beer on the wall
13 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
12 bottles of beer on the wall
12 bottles of beer on the wall
12 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
11 bottles of beer on the wall
11 bottles of beer on the wall
11 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
10 bottles of beer on the wall
10 bottles of beer on the wall
10 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
9 bottles of beer on the wall
9 bottles of beer on the wall
9 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
8 bottles of beer on the wall
8 bottles of beer on the wall
8 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
7 bottles of beer on the wall
7 bottles of beer on the wall
7 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
6 bottles of beer on the wall
6 bottles of beer on the wall
6 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
5 bottles of beer on the wall
5 bottles of beer on the wall
5 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
4 bottles of beer on the wall
4 bottles of beer on the wall
4 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
3 bottles of beer on the wall
3 bottles of beer on the wall
3 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
2 bottles of beer on the wall
2 bottles of beer on the wall
2 bottles of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
1 bottles of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer on the wall
1 bottle of beer
Take one down.
Pass it around.
No more bottles of beer on the wall
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As I understand the code out put should be start with

```
99 bottles of beer
```

because `int beerNum = 99;`

Can anyone explain me why I'm getting above output start with

```
60 bottles of beer
```

Thanks in advance.
I would be so great full if someone explain me this.

Comment: It does start with 99. Probably your console can only keep so much in it's memory.

Comment: it starts with [99 bottels of beer](http://ideone.com/3EcUNF)

Comment: I am getting `99 bottles of beer on the wall` as ouput

Answer (score 0):

Attached is the output. It indeed starts with `99 bottles of beer` .[image]